# Solving memory leak related to linked list c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks

I have a linked list which handles inserting and deleting pointers from a linked list which I made by my own implementation. Using a memory leak finder class, I continue to get a memory leak on one line and one line only....which is BOLDED in the code. Here is as follows:

```
char *name;
char phone[ PHONE_LEN ];
```

**Delete() Method for Linked List**

---

```
bool LList::Delete ( const InfoType & x )
{
   Node *p = list;
   Node *q = NULL;

   while(p->infoPtr != NULL && *(p->infoPtr) != x) //While not on node to delete
   {
      q = p;
      p = p->next;
   }
   if(p == NULL) //Empty or End
      return false;
   else if(q == NULL)//First node
   {
      list = p->next;
      delete p;
      return true;
   }
   else //middle node
   {
      q->next = p->next;
      delete p; // <- This is where I expect the delete to be taken care of
      return true;
   }
}
```

**My operator overload to directly cin Company Objects**

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Company& m)
{
   char temp[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];

   in >> temp;
   int length = strlen(temp);
   m.name = new char[length + 1]; **//This line is the one where memory leak is occurring**
   strcpy(m.name, temp);

   for(int i = 0; i < PHONE_LEN; i++)
      in >> m.phone[i];

   return in;
}
```

**Destructor if it is important**

```
Company::~Company() 
{
   if(name != NULL)
      delete [] name;
}
```

My question is this: How am I supposed to delete the object that is created in the line as pointed above inside of my delete method in the Linked List class? I will edit and post any other help about my program that I can.

EDIT:

```
struct Node
   {
      Node ( InfoType * x, Node * p = NULL ) { infoPtr = x;  next = p; }
      ~Node() { delete infoPtr; }
      InfoType * infoPtr;
      Node * next;
   };

   Node * list;
```

Comment: What, if any, is the relationship between `Node` and `Company`? Why are you showing the destructor of the latter, when your list manipulates the former? Let me guess: `Company` derives from `Node`, but `Node` doesn't have a virtual destructor (whereupon `delete p` exhibits undefined behavior).

Comment: My guess: Node::infoPtr points to a Company, but Node's destructor doesn't delete it.

Comment: I added the Node code which is a private Struct of LinkedList. The infopointer holds the Company Object.

Comment: When you set m.name to a new char array, what happens to the char array that m.name was previously pointing to?  It looks like it just gets forgotten, i.e. leaked.

Comment: (and the obligatory question:  why aren't you using std::string to hold your string data, rather than a dynamically allocated character array?  That would make it much much easier to avoid memory leaks)

Comment: That is my question is how/where would I be able to delete that so that the value which it is pointing to can still be held in the linked list until a later time?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner put up an answer with that comment. It led me intuitively to find the answer. I found that I had to include the line: delete [] m.name; before I reassign.